# ThreeTenABP: DateTimeParseException

Tags: android, date, datetime, threetenbp

Trying to change date formats of a String but getting DateTimeException:

```
String oldDate = "2018-12-18T17:04:56+00:00";
String outputFormat = "DD-MM";
try {
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(oldDate);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    return localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputFormat);
} catch (DateTimeException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    return "";
}
```

Error I am getting is: 
**Text '2018-12-18T17:04:56+00:00' could not be parsed at index 19**

I'm using com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.1 since I cannot use Java 8 classes

Comment: I think you intended lowercase `dd` in `dd-MM` (uppercase `DD` is for day of *year*).

Comment: If you want an `Instant`, I consider this way somewhat elegant: `Instant instant = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(oldDate, Instant::from);`.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse(                // Represent a moment, a date with time-of-day in the context of an offset-from-UTC (some number of hours-minutes-seconds).
    "2018-12-18T17:04:56+00:00"      // Input string in standard ISO 8601 format, with an indicator of an offset-from-UTC of zero hours and zero minutes, meaning UTC itself.
)                                    // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
.atZoneSameInstant(                  // Adjust our moment from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.systemDefault()           // Using the JVM’s current default time zone. NOTE: this default can change at any moment during runtime. If important, confirm with the user.
)                                    // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                          // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended by appending the name of the zone in square brackets. Returns a `String` object.
```

> 2018-12-18T09:04:56-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

## Details

Here is example Java code using [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, which is extended by [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) for pre-26 Android.

```
import org.threeten.bp.*;
```

### Wrong formatter

The [`Instant.parse`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) command uses the [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) formatter. That formatter expects a `Z` on the end to indicate UTC.

The `Instant` class is the basic building-block class of *java.time* framework. For more flexibility, use the `OffsetDateTime`. Its default formatter [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) can handle your input.

```
String input = "2018-12-18T17:04:56+00:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-12-18T17:04:56Z

### Wrong class

Do not use [`LocalDateTime`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDateTime.html) for tracking a moment. That class purposely lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). It is simply a date and a time-of-day. As such, it *cannot* represent a moment, is never a point on the timeline. Instead, this class represents *potential* moments along a range of 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

To track a moment, use only:

- [`Instant`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Instant.html)
  A moment in UTC, always UTC.
- [`OffsetDateTime`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/OffsetDateTime.html)
  A date, a time-of-day, with an offset-from-UTC. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, nothing more.
- [`ZonedDateTime`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZonedDateTime.html)
  A moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, a time zone. A zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used in a particular region.

To adjust our `OffsetDateTime` from UTC to some time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // If important, confirm the zone with user rather than depending on the JVM’s current default zone.
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-12-18T09:04:56-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

With these results, we see that 5 PM in UTC is simultaneously 9 AM on most of the west coast of North America. The difference of `-08:00` means on this date, the west coast was eight hours *behind* UTC.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what about the usage of DateTimeFormatter? I need to display the received date in a different format than the one I receive.

Comment: @moyo Using `DateTimeFormatter` has been [covered many many times](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=datetimeformatter+java+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=osx&ia=web) already on Stack Overflow. Pay attention to your formatting codes – they are **case-sensitive**. And you might find [`MonthDay`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/MonthDay.html) class helpful.